# error CS1729: The type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a constructor that takes `1' arguments

Tags: random, arguments, range, unity-game-engine

I've done some elementary coding in the past, and I'm now learning Unity and trying some things with C#.

My problem:

I have a list of objects that have their own id number in the range of 1-50. I want my game to pick one object at random instead of going over the list in order. The first step would be to pick the initial id to be some random number, but I only get the error: "error CS1729: The type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a constructor that takes`1' arguments". I understand that I should give more argument for the constructor, but I need help in seeing how, since the code looks fine (if simple) to me.

Anyway, it goes like this at the moment:

```
public int id;

public int randomid;

public void RandId(int id)
{
    Random randomid = new Random(Random.Range(1, 51));
    id = randomid;
    return id;
}
```

Here id is the identification number of the objects, randomid is for randomizing it, and I use Random.Range to create the wanted range (1-50). It seems I need to give more arguments to Random.Range, but it already has both min and max.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other things wrong w/ your code, but this should be what you need.

```
public void SetIDToRandom(out int id)
{
    id = (int)Random.Range(1, 51);
}
```

Addendum:

**Random** is a static class, you don't directly instantiate it.